# ConjugateGradient in Eigen for Hermitian Matrices

Tags: eigen

in the literature the conjugate gradient method is typically presented for real symmetric positive-definite matrices. However, in the description of the CG method in the Eigen library:
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__IterativeLinearSolvers__Module.html
one can find the statement:
"ConjugateGradient for selfadjoint (hermitian) matrices"

This implies that it should also work for Hermitian (complex, not purely real) matrices. Is that the case?

A minimal example shows that it actually doesn't work naively with Hermitian matrices. Is there a trick that one needs to know or is this an error in the description?

My minimal example uses the spin 3/2 matrices Sx (real symmetric) and Sy (complex Hermitian), whose Eigenvalues are know to be -1.5,-0.5,0.5,1.5.

The results for the real symmetric case are fine but in the complex case it results in a NaN.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <complex>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers>

int main(int args, char **argv){

  Eigen::VectorXcd b=Eigen::VectorXcd::Ones(4);    
  Eigen::VectorXcd x;

  std::complex<double> i_unit(0,1);

//Hermitian matrix:
  Eigen::MatrixXcd A(4,4);
  A<<0,-i_unit*sqrt(3.)/2., 0 ,0,  \
     i_unit*sqrt(3.)/2., 0 ,-i_unit, 0,\
     0,i_unit,0,-i_unit*sqrt(3.)/2.,\
     0,0,i_unit*sqrt(3.)/2.,0;

//Real symmetric matrix:
  Eigen::MatrixXcd B(4,4);
  B<<0,sqrt(3.)/2., 0 ,0,  \
     sqrt(3.)/2., 0 ,1, 0,\
     0,1,0,sqrt(3.)/2.,\
     0,0,sqrt(3.)/2.,0;

  Eigen::ConjugateGradient< Eigen::MatrixXcd, Eigen::Lower|Eigen::Upper> cg;
  cg.compute(A);
  x = cg.solve(b);

  std::cout<<"Hermitian matrix:"<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"A: "<<std::endl<<A<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"b: "<<std::endl<<b<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"x: "<<std::endl<<x<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"(b-A*x).norm(): "<<(b-A*x).norm()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"cg.error(): "<<cg.error()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<std::endl;

  cg.compute(B);
  x = cg.solve(b);
  std::cout<<"Real symmetric matrix:"<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"B: "<<std::endl<<B<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"b: "<<std::endl<<b<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"x: "<<std::endl<<x<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"(b-B*x).norm(): "<<(b-B*x).norm()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"cg.error(): "<<cg.error()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hermitian is not enough, it also needs to be **positive definite** which is not your case since your matrix has both positive and negative eigenvalues. Anyways, CG is rather designed for handling very large sparse matrices, for a 4x4 matrix better use a dense decomposition. In your case, `LDLT` will do well.